# Question about integral and change of variables

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ integrable $\beta: [c,d] \to [a,b]$ differentiable. Define $\Phi:[c,d] \to \mathbb{R}$ this way

$\Phi(x) = \displaystyle \int_a^{\beta(x)}f(t)dt$

a) Show that $\Phi$ is well defined.

b) Show that $\Phi(x)$ is differentiable and $\Phi'(x)=f(\beta(x))\beta'(x).$

$\textbf{My effort:}$

a) I have to prove that $\Phi$ is function? cause $f$ is integrable then given $x_0 \in [c,d]$, we have that $\Phi(x_0)= \displaystyle \int_a^{\beta(x_0)}f(t)dt = F(\beta(x_0))- F(a)$. So, the value is unic. Is that correct?

b)How can I start that? Is kind of obvious by change of variable theorem, but I wanna formalize that, can you help me?

Comment: For b) write your map as a composition and use the chain rule.

Comment: $\Phi(x) = F(\beta(x)) - F(a)$?

Comment: That's exactly right.

Comment: For (b) to hold for a fixed $x_0  \in [c,d]$, we need to assume that $f$ is continuous at $\beta(x_0)$ and that $\beta$ is the difference of two monotone increasing functions in a neighborhood of $x_0$.  In other words, in order to prove (b), we need the additional assumptions that $f$ is continuous on $\beta([c,d]) \subset [a,b]$ and that $\beta$ is the difference of two monotone increasing functions on $[c,d]$. I am pretty sure that the second assumption is needed. Definitely, the first assumption is needed. This all according to my attempt to provide a solution to part (b).